# sending (or receiving) messages in parallel with gRPC streams

Tags: go, grpc, grpc-go

According to [link1](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc#ClientStream) and [link2](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc#ServerStream), it's not safe to call SendMsg (or RecvMsg) on the same stream in different goroutines. Why? What's the reason behind it? My program panics when receiving responses at client side, or I receive some errors (context related, EOF, or "received message larger than max..."). I don't understand why this is happening when each request is independent from others.

Thanks!

Comment: It’s a _stream_, how would it make sense to call send and recv concurrently on a stream?

Comment: Based on the documentation, you can have one goroutine for send and one goroutine for receive.  That's not my problem. My problem is I can't understand why we can't have multiple goroutines for send. Why can't we send Request1 at the same time as Request2, when each request is independent.

Comment: A stream is an _ordered_ series of bytes (or messages in the case of grpc). Calling `SendMsg` concurrently means there would be no defined order of messages sent, and calling `RecvMsg` concurrently means there would be no way to determine which message was received. You would not call send and recv on a `SOCK_STREAM` connection concurrently, so that same concept is applied here.

Comment: @M.S. are you talking about sending _messages_ in the same stream (same RPC call) or making different RPC calls or sending messages in different RPC calls concurrently? Because that documentation is about sending messages within a single streaming RPC (so it is one "request").

Comment: @JimB What forces a grpc stream to be an ordered series of messages? Is it something like a sequence number in HTTP headers or some metadata? Does this mean for stateless scenario we should use unary RPC?

Comment: @YuriGolobokov I meant sending messages within a single stream.

Comment: @M.S., because by definition a "stream" ordered. The order is enforced by the order of the messages in the stream, they cannot arrive out of order. Having messages overlap in the stream because they were sent concurrently is going to break the message framing. You either need to add your own synchronization, or since order doesn't matter to you, use multiple streams.

Answer (score 0):

The best summary of the reasons "we do not want to enable concurrent SendMsg calls at this time" I can find is from dfawley in [issue 2356](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/pull/2356#issuecomment-431202999):

> 1. Because ordering often does matter for streams, it could be confusing for users if we allowed this.
> 2. Streams not attempting this type of operation become penalized by the cost of taking this mutex.
> 3. Similarly, in a heavily loaded system, attempting to send in parallel will not end up leading to any performance gains; the CPU and network are already fully saturated, and the cost of synchronization becomes a negative.
> 4. If we were to allow this, the issue of fairness arises pretty quickly thereafter. sync.Mutexes have no concept of fairness, so it's possible that even if the user implements their own message reordering on the receiving end, one message could be postponed until many subsequent messages (hundreds/thousands/more) have been sent. This could result in problems for users not expecting that possibility - e.g. if they are buffering a message until all prior messages are received.